# How to find select elements in a div with id hook, the selected elements must not have parent with class .select-box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find select elements in a div with id hook, the selected elements must not have parent with class .select-box

HTML code

```
<div id="hook">
   .
   .
   some elements here
    .
    .
    <select class="a">
        <option>Full-time</option>
    </select>

    <div id="select-box">
        <select class="a"> <!--  DO NOT SELECT THIS  -->
            <option>Full-time</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <select class="a">
        <option>Full-time</option>
    </select>
    <select class="a">
        <option>Full-time</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
$('#hook').find('select').each(function(e) {
    fun($(this));
});
```

**Edit**

select element is nested in some more elements.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#hook > select')`

`>` means to only select direct descendants of what is selected before it. So only direct children of `#hook` that are select elements will be selected.

Comment: `>` will not work here as select is nested in some more elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hook :not(.select-box) select').each((i, e) =>
  fun($(e))
)
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/MoMolog/pen/wvBqQep

Comment: @Syed It is a jQuery solution.